# How to calculate entropy of joint distribution?

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, entropy

There are two random variables `X` and `Y` and their joint probability `Posterior_P`(discrete, 2D-array), I got the entropy of posterior probability by using [scipy.stats.entropy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html), which returns an array with dimension `len(X)` because the default axis = 0. I am totally new to entropy so please correct me if I confused certain definitions. 
I created a fairly simple example to testify:

```
x = np.arange(-2,2,0.01)
y = np.arange(-2,2,0.01)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

# support area
sup = np.dstack((X,Y))

distribution = multivariate_normal(mean=[0,0],cov=[[1,0],[0,1]])

# This is what I want, returns a value = 2.83
entropy_0 = distribution.entropy()

# calculate from 2-D array PDF 
# returns an array [8.4605,8.4605,...,8.4605] with a size of len(X)
pdf = distribution.pdf(sup)
entropy_1 = entropy(pdf,base=2)
```

What's the difference between them and how can I get the overall entropy from joint density which supposed to be a value using [scipy.stats.entropy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html)?

Comment: FYI:  `scipy.stats.entropy` computes the (discrete) [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)), and `multivariate_normal.entropy` computes the [differential entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy).  They are not the same.  Which one do you really want?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I want to calculate the entropy of a joint distribution. Because I use `meshgrid` to define the support, the pdf of joint distribution is actually a 2D array. When I tried `entropy` it returns a 1D array with a length of `X` rather than a single value. But based on the definition, the entropy should be the summation of `P(x,y)*log1/(P(x,y))` over the support space, which would be a single value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`scipy.stats.entropy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html) computes the entropy of a *discrete* distribution.  The values are expected to be probabilities, not probability densities. (In fact, if the sum of the values in the input is not 1, the values are scaled so the sum is 1.  This is mentioned in the docstring.)  If that is what you have (e.g. the 2-d array `p` holds the joint distribution probabilities of a bivariate discrete distribution) you can simply pass the flattened array to `scipy.stats.entropy`; e.g. `entropy(p.ravel(), base=2)`.

The function `scipy.stats.entropy` does not compute the same mathematical quantity as the `entropy` method of a scipy continuous distribution such as `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal`.  The `entropy` method computes the differential entropy of the distribution.   See the [wikipedia article on differential entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy) for a discussion of the difference between the discrete entropy computed by `scipy.stats.entropy` and the differential entropy computed by the `entropy` method of the scipy distributions.